# Select query that iterates through the results of a first query

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is the code we have at the moment that works fine as a select query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  Reference,
  (SELECT
    amount
  FROM tbl_DDTransactions
  WHERE DueDate = '2015-01-15'
  AND Reference = 'MAIN0134')
  AS LastMonth,
  (SELECT
    amount
  FROM tbl_DDTransactions
  WHERE DueDate = '2015-02-15'
  AND Reference = 'MAIN0134')
  AS CurrentMonth
FROM tbl_DDTransactions
WHERE Reference = 'MAIN0134'
```

The table we are pulling this information from can have any number of entries (each row actually relates to a transaction with the company reference as MAINxxxx).

What we would like to do is gets a list a value of distinct MAIN references in the table, then have it loop through the code above, generating a row for each MAIN reference. We're not quite sure how to express this in SQL though. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select  r.reference,
        a1.amount as lastMonth,
        a2.amount as currentMonth
from    (select distinct reference from tbl_DDTransactions) as r
        left join tbl_DDTransactions a1 on a1.reference = r.reference and a1.DueDate = '2015-01-15' 
        left join tbl_DDTransactions a2 on a2.reference = r.reference and a2.DueDate = '2015-02-15'
```

Answer (score 0):

May be `pivot` is what you are looking for

```
SELECT Reference,
       [2015-01-15] LastMonth,
       [2015-02-15] CurrentMonth
FROM   yourtable
       PIVOT (Max(amount)
             FOR DueDate IN([2015-01-15],
                            [2015-02-15]))piv
WHERE  Reference = 'MAIN0134'
```

Note: The above can be modified to work dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

At the first glance this looks like a simple aggregate:

```
SELECT
  Reference, 
  sum(case when DueDate = '2015-01-15' then amount end) AS LastMonth,
  sum(case when DueDate = '2015-02-15' then amount end) AS CurrentMonth
FROM tbl_DDTransactions
GROUP BY Reference
```